# Woocommerce price in cart updates after a second

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have small plugin that enables customers for easy selection of different quantities. I managed to make code works but I got a "small" issue. After user adds to cart 2 products or more, he gets bulk price discount, but in my case discounted price in mini cart shows only for second, then it's overwritten with default product price. And in cart and on checkout is default product price.

I'm not professional coder so this are just my learning steps where I do need some help .

So here is my code for changing price:

``

```
// Update cart price
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'woo_bq_update_cart_price', 10, 1);
function woo_bq_update_cart_price($cart)
{
  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
  return;

  if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
    return;
  
    // Check if the 'woo_bq_selected_percentage' field is set
    if (isset($_POST['woo_bq_selected_percentage'])) {
      // Retrieve the selected percentage
      $selected_percentage = floatval($_POST['woo_bq_selected_percentage']);
  
      // Apply the discount to each item in the cart
      foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $product_price = get_post_meta($product_id, '_price', true);
        $new_price = $product_price - ($product_price * ($selected_percentage / 100));
        $cart_item['data']->set_price($new_price);
      }
    }
  /* Logging
  function woo_bq_log_data($message)
  {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $log_file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/woo-bq-logs.log';
    $log_message = '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '] ' . $message . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($log_file, $log_message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
  }
  woo_bq_log_data('Form submitted: ' . print_r($_POST, true));
  */
}
``
```

What I have tried so far:
- changing hooks from woocommerce_before_calculate_totals to all that makes some sense
- changing priority from 10 to 1000
- searching for errors in logs (nothing...)
- disable all plugins except my own and woocommerce
- disable flatsome theme and move to default 2023 theme
- using ChatGPT for help

Thank you for all your advices and help.